# ES 6.x, join type, when parent and child doc have the same field. store it as one field or two?

Tags: elasticsearch

As we know, ES6.x store parent and child type in one document one type.

My model is:

```
parent: {id, name, point}
child:  {id, point}
```

What is the suggestion to design es document?

```
{id, name, point} or {id, name, point, child_point}
```

The question is: when parent and child have the field with the same name, should I store it in one field or two?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go both ways. Which one to go depends on what kind of queries you want to perform against parent and child documents.

#### if you reuse field names

Let's say, you make `name` reused field name.

You can query all documents by `name` - parent documents will be returned along with child documents. This may be undesirable (or may be not, depends on what you want).

In order to query by name only parent or only child documents you can still use a [`must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html) like this: `name: X AND type: parent` (or child).

If you reuse `text` fields, the relevance scoring might be affected - because a field with the same name will use the same inverted index, and `parent` token frequencies will affect relevance of `child` text searches.

#### if you don't reuse field names

Let's say you decide for parent documents to only populate "parent fields", and for child documents - only "child fields". For example, in parent you would use `name` and in child `childName`.

In this case to search for only parent documents by name it would be enough to use one query: `name: X`. To search for only child documents by name: `childName: X`.

If you will need to mix the results (parent and child documents in the same result set) you can still combine these two queries via a [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

The index for full text search of parent's `name` will not affect that one of `childName`.

#### So, which one to choose?

`has_child` and `has_parent` queries seem to not affect the choice, since they will distinguish the parent from child automatically.

Select reuse of the fields if you do a lot of queries that query parent and child documents in the same way.

Otherwise, do not reuse the field names.

Hope that helps!